# both USB ports randomly stop working, then when shutdown, stuck on blinking cursor

Tags: linux, usb, shutdown, kernel-module

the problem usually occurs about once per day, seemingly at random, but occasionally two times, and occasionally zero times.

devices connected are: a new STAR printer with it's own power supply, connected using a parallel to USB cable, and a low cost wired barcode scanner.

ever since this problem began, i have added the follow kernel parameters to `/etc/default/grub` though the problem continues:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet usbcore.autosuspend=-1 acpi=force apm=power_off irqpoll"
```

the computer in use is a thinkpad X200 running latest debian. hibernate and suspend are disabled on an OS level. i have tried changing the two USB related options in the BIOS but they don't seem to make a difference.

when the error occurs, the computer will not shutdown properly, and hangs on a blinking cursor on a blank screen. the computer shuts down completely normally if it is shutdown before the error occurs.

i have not tested a copy of the OS on other hardware, or the computer with a different OS.

note that the failing USB ports are a bigger issue for me than the failing shutdown.

the USB devices continue working as normal after a reboot, which suggests a software based problem to me, and hopefully an easy fix.

**update**: the error last occurred at 11:53 and 150 lines of the `/var/log/messages` file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/P1KYGRqp

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to resolve this question. Does the port shutdown occur with any USB device, or with only particular devices? What kind of devices they are? It sounds like an issue with USB port power management. Even if the core does not go into SUSPEND, the USB stack will continue to operate USB ports with all possible power management (PM) means. The issues with PM on local links have plagued the USB industry with many problems. To rule out if the link PM is an issue, try to use only formally USB-certified devices, if you can find one :-(

Comment: yes it is connected to an official STAR printer, but also to a low cost barcode scanner from ebay, though the STAR printer has it's own seperate power supply, and the barcode scanner's product page claims to use maximum 110mA

Comment: You said that the printer is "connected using a parallel to USB cable". This is a highly suspicious connection. The X200 is a pretty mature design with regard to usb, and it has 3 USB ports. If you connect your printer and scanner directly to on-board USB ports, does the same hangup occur? Did you try to put a good hub between your devices and X200?

Comment: In the other thread   [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297381/both-usb-ports-randomly-stop-working)     you posted a log at the point of failure. The log says that some "full-speed" keyboard from "Megawin Technology" gets disconnected. What is your full USB connectivity for your system?

Comment: oh yes all devices are plugged directly into the thinkpad, no USB hub is used, if that's what you mean. you're thinking that a hub, perhaps with separate power supply, would fix the problem ? yes the barcode scanner is what's recognised as a keyboard, there was no standard keyboard plugged into the thinkpad at any point. only the STAR printer and the barcode scanner is ever plugged in. yes the parallel to USB cable is cheap, though all the parallel-USB cables on amazon and ebay looked exactly the same, except for one cable on amazon i favorited that i could buy, which had high reviews.

Comment: i do have another similar, low cost scanner that i could try tomorrow. also, it's a temporary annual shop so i will probably test the thinkpad for personal use with completely different peripherals at a later point

Comment: I don't think that power distribution is the root of your problem. But who knows. When I suggested the hub, I mean that the host data flow will be drastically different, and FS-LS devices behind the hub will be controlled via a different hub-dedicated driver, which will use HS "split transactions" (instead of going via separate internal UHCI controller, which is FS/LS only). This experiment will determine if this is a software issue with host drivers, or an issue with the scanner. I still don't understand how a scanner can be controlled via a keyboard-class driver.

Comment: This is not a "discussion" or "chat". In semiconductor and computer industry is is called "DEBUG". Which is a systematic approach to eliminate possible causes and find the true root cause on an issue and proper workaround. Your approach as "perfect question" has "perfect answer" does not work in reality. To be productive, the forum should allow for a system of guided questions, additional experiments, and answers to intermediate hypotheses.

Comment: i'm of the understanding that the scanner's firmware converts the barcodes to numbers, and the computer just interprets the input as a keyboard. but i might have to try the hub